# CentOS 7 - while installing i set disk encrypted with password, but on reboot always it asking password

Tags: centos, boot, system-installation, password, encryption

While installing CentOS 7, i put password for disk encrypt. Now while working remotely on that machine and doing reboot it always ask password to be inserted on-site.

Is this normal? or there is a way still keep disk encrypted but make the reboot work?

Comment: What is the point of encryption if someone can bypass it by simply turning the machine on?

Comment: Correct. I have never done this before. Is this how everyone else is doing till today too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very normal, and it is because disk is in list of disks to be automatically mounted. If you don't want to be asked for password, you should remove encrypted disk from `/etc/fstab`. After doing this, you will be prompted for password only when you want to mount encrypted disk.

**Good luck!**